# SQLite3 with PHP How to do Cross Referencing of Columns with data found in other Columns

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, cross-reference

Here is how my Sample data looks like

```
hwid: 1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace
ip: 68.197.140.109 
character name: none
```

```
hwid: 1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace
ip: 219.100.37.236
character name: none
```

```
hwid: 1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50acd 
ip: 68.197.140.109 
character name: kalgame
```

Now say I'm logging in with 
this hwid
1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace
and this ip address
219.100.37.236

which has a link to using a previous `IP` address of `68.197.140.109`
and that `IP` address has a link to a 3rd `hwid` that has a `character name : kalgame`.

Thats what I need to do cross referencing with all `IP's` linked to all `hwid's` and then check if any of those `hwid's` have a `character_name`.
If they have a `character_name` associated to them return them in a `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(totalMatchesOfUniqueCharacterNames)`

I also need to check if the `current HWID` or `current IP` you are using has 3 days trial period, if it does then also add it to the `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT`.. then I could easily check in PHP if SELECT DISTINCT COUNT is greater then 1, then abort giving out any more free trials to the specific user as he already logged in before with a `character_name`, and also maybe had a 3 day trial period before hand on either his PC `hwid` or his `IP` address, note I would also like to exclude blank `character_name's` as those players didn't login with a character yet.. so they don't count. I also have to match the `locale` which is which game are they playing if they are playing a different game then they also don't count.

Here is my attempt at cross referencing I been working at this for 6 hours and today is my first day using SQLite or any SQL in general so I have no clue what i'm doing

Here is my table schema DDL for both tables.. they are also both in the same database file.

```
CREATE TABLE ips (
    hwid           VARCHAR,
    ip             VARCHAR,
    character_name VARCHAR,
    locale         VARCHAR,
    botver         VARCHAR,
    reg_time       DATETIME,
    last_time      DATETIME,
    ping_count     INTEGER  DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    hwid      VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    timestamp INTEGER,
    daysToUse INTEGER,
    pcLimit   INTEGER,
    comment   VARCHAR
);
```

Here is my attempt at putting it all together

```
SELECT users2.hwid,
       ips2.character_name,
       ips2.ip
  FROM users AS users2
       INNER JOIN
       ips AS ips2 ON ips2.hwid = users2.hwid
 WHERE EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
             FROM users
                  INNER JOIN
                  ips ON ips.hwid = users.hwid
            WHERE ips.character_name != '' AND 
                  ips.locale = ips2.locale AND 
                  (ips.hwid = '1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace' OR 
                   ips.ip = '219.100.37.236') AND 
                  EXISTS (
                          SELECT 1
                            FROM users
                                 INNER JOIN
                                 ips ON ips.hwid = users.hwid
                           WHERE ips.character_name != '' AND 
                                 ips2.ip = ips.ip AND 
                                 ips2.locale = ips.locale
                      )
       )
OR 
       (ips2.hwid = '1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace' AND 
        users2.daysToUse = 3) OR 
       (ips2.ip = '219.100.37.236' AND 
        users2.daysToUse = 3);
```

Here is what I left in the production website.. which isn't that good.. doesn't do cross referencing that well skips certain columns but atleast it kinda works unlike the top code above which just sounds like it should work but doesn't work at all.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users2.hwid) 
  FROM users AS users2
       INNER JOIN
       ips AS ips3 ON ips3.hwid = users2.hwid
 WHERE ips3.character_name = (
                                 SELECT ips.character_name
                                   FROM users,
                                        ips AS ips2
                                        INNER JOIN
                                        ips ON ips.hwid = users.hwid
                                  WHERE ips.character_name != '' AND 
                                        ips.locale = ips2.locale AND 
                                        (ips.hwid = '$HWID' OR 
                                         ips.ip = '$IP') 
                             )
OR 
       (ips3.hwid = '$HWID' AND 
        users2.daysToUse = 3) OR 
       (ips3.ip = '$IP' AND 
        users2.daysToUse = 3);
```

If anyone can help me out i will be forever grateful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your subqueries share same `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses, simplify to a compact `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT i.ip, i.character_name, u.hwid, u.daysToUse, i.locale 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN ips i
   ON i.hwid = u.hwid 
WHERE (i.hwid = '1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace'
        AND u.daysToUse = 3) 
   OR (i.ip = '219.100.37.236' AND u.daysToUse = 3) 
ORDER BY i.last_time
```

Comment: the `i` the table is called `ips` doesn't work `[21:45:21] Error while executing SQL query on database 'botusers': no such table: i`

Comment: You mean like `INNER JOIN ips i` ?

Comment: Yes, fixed that typo.

Comment: Ya your query doesn't do cross referencing with all other `character_name's` that are associated to either the `ip` or `hwid` just not explicitly

Comment: just noticed my query is also bugged the last_time even though it seems like a nice quickfix won't work either.. because it doesn't do cross referencing with other IP's addresses which share the same hwid those ip's could have a higher last_time meaning they should show up instead of my current ip. Actually nevermind I do a OR for IP or Hwid check so it should pick up both IP's

Comment: Haha ya looks like both our queries give the same result.. i need to do more testing but it looks like i'll end up going with yours as it's simpler lol. Wonder if I even need cross referencing on character_names.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I used your posted answer not your question code to pare down the redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.. turns out it is very simple to do this, I just had the query done in backwards order I flipped the order and bam it works as expected.

The locale problem was hard.. I couldn't detect which locale is currently used, so I relayed on using `ips.lasttime` which shows which `IP` or `HWID` was used last, and being used last its obviously the locale I want to check

Final result

```
SELECT ips.ip,
       ips.character_name,
       users.hwid,
       users.daysToUse,
       ips.locale
  FROM users
       INNER JOIN
       ips ON ips.hwid = users.hwid
 WHERE ips.ip IN (
           SELECT ips.ip
             FROM users
                  INNER JOIN
                  ips ON ips.hwid = users.hwid
            WHERE (ips.hwid = '1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace' AND 
                   users.daysToUse = 3) OR 
                  (ips.ip = '219.100.37.236' AND 
                   users.daysToUse = 3) 
       )
AND 
       ips.locale = (
           SELECT ips.locale
             FROM users
                  INNER JOIN
                  ips ON ips.hwid = users.hwid
            WHERE (ips.hwid = '1502e3c3-b49c-4907-92fd-2ffac2d50ace' AND 
                   users.daysToUse = 3) OR 
                  (ips.ip = '219.100.37.236' AND 
                   users.daysToUse = 3) ORDER BY ips.last_time ASC
       );
```

Comment: Be careful not to reuse aliases like *ips* in subqueries.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that would be a problem as I got the sub-queries in binary brackets which means they won't leave that scope I guess, and I could only access the outer scope if I used the `AS` command I think. It even looks easier to read if I do like `ips1` , `ips2` it turns very messy thats how I started out with.